# fetching content by id and displaying by url php mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sql

i have two column in my DB films

1. filmId
2. url(name of the film)

I have no idea how it that possible:

I want to fetch data by `filmId` but display(after clicking) with url which is having film name

for example "million-dollar-arm".

why I want to do that because I have a separate table of song and if that film is having song (will match the `filmid` in song table and it will display the songs) that film

```
$url=$_GET['url'];
$sql = "SELECT * FROM films WHERE url='$url'";
```

i need help to do this using php as i am very new and know little of php.

Table Structure
Film table

filmId
filmName
url
director
actor

Song table

songId
songName
filmId
filmName

Comment: films is the name of your database or is it a table? If you can give also your table structure, the better.

Comment: show your example url also?

Comment: @ Rakesh http://www.efilmsworld.com/million-dollar-arm-film-2014.html this is i have already done using htaccess as i am fetching by url but not able to display the songs of that film

Comment: you can Join two tables films and songs By left join or Inner join.

Comment: soo are you having trouble iterating through the result set?

Answer (score 1):

Use Below code:

```
$url=$_GET['url']; 
$sql = "SELECT * FROM songs s 
inner join films f on s.filmId = f.filmId 
WHERE f.url='$url'";

$result = mysql_query($sql);
while($row = mysql_fetch_object($result)){
    print_r($row);
}
```

Comment: Hi Harry thanks a lot, it worked but one issue is left it displays only one song of the film, but i want to display all the songs of that film which is having same filmid in song table

Comment: @RRPandey: then you need to change your query.

Comment: $url=$_GET['url'];
$sql = "SELECT * FROM songs s
inner join films f on s.filmId = f.filmId 
WHERE f.url='$url'";

Comment: no luck '$url=$_GET['url']; $sql = "SELECT * FROM songs s inner join films f on s.filmId = f.filmId WHERE f.url='$url'"; and echoing this 'echo "<iframe width=\"320\" height=\"240\" src=\"youtube.com/embed/$songVideo\" frameborder=\"0\" allowfullscreen></iframe>";'

Comment: @ Harry no luck $url=$_GET['url'];
$sql = "SELECT * FROM songs s inner join films f on s.filmId = f.filmId WHERE f.url='$url'";

$result = mysql_query($sql);
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
 {
$filmId=$row['filmId'];$filmName=$row['filmName'];$url=$row['url'];.......etc.
$songVideo=$row['songVideo'];$songName=$row['songName'];......etc.

  echo "$filmName";
  ------
  ------
  etc.
  
  echo "<div id=\"videoSmall\">\n";
  echo "<iframe width=\"320\" height=\"240\" src=\"http://www.youtube.com/embed/$songVideo\" frameborder=\"0\" allowfullscreen></iframe>";
  echo "</div>\n";

Comment: @RRPandey: please share your code, so i can help you more. Because its working for me.

Comment: code
    $url=$_GET['url'];
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM songs s inner join films f on s.filmId = f.filmId WHERE f.url='$url'";
        $result = mysql_query($sql);
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
         { $filmId=$row['filmId'];$filmName=$row['filmName'];$url=$row['url'];
        $songVideo=$row['songVideo'];$songName=$row['songName'];
echo "$filmName";
//film details
//song details
echo "<div id=\"videoSmall\">\n";
echo "<iframe width=\"320\" height=\"240\" src=\"http://www.youtube.com/embed/$songVideo\" frameborder=\"0\" allowfullscreen></iframe>";
echo "</div>\n";

Comment: @ harry here is the link http://www.efilmsworld.com/tmp.php?url=besharam-film-2013

Comment: SELECT * FROM songs s 
inner join films f on s.filmId = f.filmId 
WHERE f.url='besharam-film-2013'

Comment: @RRPandey: run above query in database directly and check how many records you get. other then there are not any issue in code.

Comment: you are right code is perfect but not sure why it displays only one song. after queried it displays all song having same filmid

Comment: @hary this query also not displaying films those are not having songs